# finding the correct time complexity of these codes

Tags: java, loops, time-complexity

I was trying to find time complexity of these 2 codes but i am not sure about my answers .

**code1**

```
   int i = 1;
    int count = 0;
   
    while (i < n) {

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            count++;
        }
        i *= 2;
    }
```

I calculated the number of steps in loops and I reached to **(log n)^2** but i am not sure about it .

**Code2**

```
int k=0;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = 2; j * j <= i; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                k++;
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

and for this one I got **( n * log n)**

actually I am new to calculating time complexity and I am not sure about them , could you help me find the correct answer .

Comment: Seems like you are correct.

Comment: in the second code i think you should make `k++` out of the if Statement